# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Hello I realize there are multiple people with a similar issue but the reason for me adding this as a new question is because this is an adapter with two holders. I have a `listview` that has a header cell and the information cell. the error that I am encountering its

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView.

Which only happens when I scroll the list down and then go back up. I am assuming the `holder` is getting destroyed and when I call the line to add text the holder is null but I am not sure. Thank you for your help in advance!

Custom Adapter:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<sources> {

    private ArrayList<sources> sources_list = new ArrayList<sources>();
    private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<sources> sources_list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, sources_list);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final sources item) {
        sources_list.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSectionHeaderItem(final sources item) {
        sources_list.add(item);
        sectionHeader.add(sources_list.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return sources_list.size();
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public sources getItem(int position) {
        return sources_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    public class ViewHolder2 {
        TextView separator;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        ViewHolder2 holder2 = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
        int rowType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            switch (rowType) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.source_cell, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.code = (TextView)
                            convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
                    holder.name = (CheckBox)
                            convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    break;

                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    holder2 = new ViewHolder2();
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.source_header, null);
                    holder2.separator = (TextView)
                            convertView.findViewById(R.id.separator);
                    break;
            }

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            if (rowType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                holder = (ViewHolder)
                        convertView.getTag(R.layout.source_cell);
            } else {
                holder2 = (ViewHolder2) convertView.getTag(R.layout.source_header);
            }

        }

        if (rowType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            sources n_source = sources_list.get(position);
            holder.code.setText(n_source.getCode().toUpperCase());
            holder.name.setTag(n_source);
        } else {
            sources n_source = sources_list.get(position);
            holder2.separator.setText(n_source.getCode().toUpperCase());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setTag/getTag` appears to be wrong.  You need to use `setTag(r.layout.blah, holder)` to match your `getTag(r.layout.blah)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on my code where would you recommend making this fixes?

Comment: @paul590 remove convertView.setTag(holder) from after your switch and use convertView.setTag(R.layout.source_cell,holder) and convertView.setTag(R.layout.source_header, holder2) in the two case statments

Comment: you are the man! I looked more into my code, my issue was on the getTag() function, I was getting a tag but doing it like this getTag(R.layout.blah) and was messing with the code, i just took this out run it again and it worked. Thanks again!!